# How to show visited div' s color changed?

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

I am working on an application on which there are different videos.When user views a video the color of that video should be change so that user knows which video he views before.My code is

```
<li class="amazingcarousel-item">
    <div class="amazingcarousel-item-container">
    <div class="amazingcarousel-image">
        <a href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/92730281" class="html5lightbox" data-group="amazingcarousel-12">
            <img src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/472543369_960.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="amazingcarousel-title">Main Display</div>
        <div class="amazingcarousel-txt">How the Test Screen Look like.</div>                   
    </div>
</li>

<li class="amazingcarousel-item">
    <div class="amazingcarousel-item-container">
        <div class="amazingcarousel-image">
            <a href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/92730282" class="html5lightbox" data-group="amazingcarousel-12">
                <img src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/472543372_960.jpg" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="amazingcarousel-title">Functions</div>
        <div class="amazingcarousel-txt">Which buttons or functions you need to know</div>                  
     </div>
</li>
```

I am using following CSS for hover

```
div .amazingcarousel-item-container:hover 
{
    opacity: 0.1;
    color: red;
}
```

and I am using following for visited effect

```
div .amazingcarousel-item-container:visited 
{
    opacity: 0.1;
    color: blue;
}
```

But the problem is that hover is working correctly but visited is not working.

Comment: consider the fact that `:visited` will merely change style until the user clears their history, so won't be consistent... you will have to use a different method (eg. log state in db) to do that...

Answer (score 2):

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3avisited)

The `:visited` CSS pseudo-class lets you select only links `<a>` tag that have been visited. You cant use it with `<div>`

In your case you need to change the div class explicitly when you focus out/blur using javascript

Like

```
.visited 
{
 color: blue;
}
```

JS

```
element.ClassName=element.ClassName+ ' visited' ;
```

Comment: not working because there is a postback when video opens in a popup.

Comment: If there is a post back happens, you need to maintain the state and do it at the time of page load/ document.ready

Comment: how to maintain state in client scripting.

Answer (score 0):

`:visited` is only for `<a>` tags only.

You could add a class using jQuery and then style the class as needed.

```
$('.amazingcarousel-item-container').focus().addClass('watching');
$('.amazingcarousel-item-container').blur().removeClass('watching').addClass('watched');
```